# How to make navbar grows and shrinks when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a navbar in simple HTML and scss I want to make it in a way that it can be collapsible, for example, I would have a small button on the side of the navbar that when clicked the bar grows to show the elements ( icons and titles ) and when clicked again the navbar shrinks showing only the icons, how can I implement something like this?

```css
.page-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.list-items {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.list-item.selected {
  color: white;
}

.list-item:hover {
  color: #51bbe5;
}

.list-item:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.35;
  transform: scaleY(0.5) scaleX(2);
}

.list-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #51bbe5;
  /* set opacity to 0 by default */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.list-item.selected::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.list-item span.material-icons-outlined {
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.page-content-container {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="list-items">
      <a class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> source </span>New reconciliation
      </a>
      <a class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> source </span>Reports history
      </a>
      <a class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> drive_folder_upload </span
        >Uploaded files history
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/reports" routerLinkActive="selected" class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> description </span>Logout
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-content-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the code you provided is incomplete. Where is the "small button"? Are you using JS to trigger the menu? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: hey @disinfor the small button was just an example to clarify the desired output, the idea is i will use a button not something else like a hover..;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.create a button on which's click you want to perform this show hide,

2. When button click, check if the menu is visible then hide it, if its hidden then show it,
3. initially I have make it hidden, you can reverse it just by css, no need to alter the jQuery code, its is written in a way, that it will work weather its hidden or visible initially

if need something else, feel free to comment

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
  if($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
      $(this).next().slideUp();
      $('.show').show();
      $('.hide').hide();
  }else {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
    $('.show').hide();
    $('.hide').show();
  }
  });
});
```

```css
.page-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.list-items {
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.list-item.selected {
  color: white;
}

.list-item:hover {
  color: #51bbe5;
}

.list-item:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.35;
  transform: scaleY(0.5) scaleX(2);
}

.list-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #51bbe5;
  /* set opacity to 0 by default */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.list-item.selected::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.list-item span.material-icons-outlined {
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.page-content-container {
  padding: 50px;
}

.showHide .hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="sidebar">
  <button class="showHide"><span class="show">Show + </span><span class="hide">hide - </span></button>  
    <div class="list-items">
      <a class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> source </span>New reconciliation
      </a>
      <a class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> source </span>Reports history
      </a>
      <a class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> drive_folder_upload </span
        >Uploaded files history
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/reports" routerLinkActive="selected" class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> description </span>Logout
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-content-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

your collapsible requirement , i have changed HTML a bit just to show the output, you can have it whatever you want, if its not what you want or need, pls let me know.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
  if($('.sidebar').hasClass('shrinked')) {
      $('.sidebar').removeClass('shrinked');
      $('.show').show();
      $('.hide').hide();
      $('.list-item span').not('.material-icons-outlined').show();
  }else {
    $('.sidebar').addClass('shrinked');
    $('.show').hide();
    $('.hide').show();
    $('.list-item span').not('.material-icons-outlined').hide();
  }
  });
});
```

```css
.page-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: width 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.shrinked {width: 70px;}

.list-items {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.list-item.selected {
  color: white;
}

.list-item:hover {
  color: #51bbe5;
}

.list-item:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.35;
  transform: scaleY(0.5) scaleX(2);
}

.list-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #51bbe5;
  /* set opacity to 0 by default */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.list-item.selected::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.list-item span.material-icons-outlined {
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.page-content-container {
  padding: 50px;
}

.showHide .hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="sidebar">
  <button class="showHide"><span class="show">Show + </span><span class="hide">hide - </span></button>  
    <div class="list-items">
      <a class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> icon </span><span >New reconciliation</span>
      </a>
      <a class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> icon </span><span >Reports history</span>
      </a>
      <a class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> icon </span
        ><span >Uploaded files history</span>
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/reports" routerLinkActive="selected" class="list-item">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined"> icon </span><span >Logout</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-content-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, @Atul Rajput thank you for your answer, but I was asking how to implement a collapsable sidebar, not a drop-down menu...

Comment: NP sohail, I would love to help, but can you pls explain this a bit "collapsible sidebar,"
how you want it to behave.

Comment: only the icons, by this in your question , I got what you need, adding that into answer as well, hang tight

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Bootstrap.

In bootstrap, you need these files:

1. bootstrap.min.css
2. jquery.js
3. bootstrap.min.js

in this exact order. The jquery file is what you will need to make bootstrap buttons dropdown and collapse.

Usually I would copy the code from the getting started boilerplate and then download the assets to my local for development.

Answer (score 0):

if you want by default to display only the icons, add

```
.material-icons-outlined {
        display: none;
    }
```

to a stylesheet file and add a button in your html file

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

and edit

```
<a class="list-item">
   <span class="material-icons-outlined"> source </span>New reconciliation
</a>
```

to

```
<a  class="list-item"> icon 1 
<span class="material-icons-outlined"> source New reconciliation</span>
                </a>
                <a class="list-item"> icon 2 
                    <span class="material-icons-outlined"> source Reports history</span>
</a>
```

since you are using a class, you should add indexes in your function. example

```
function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("material-icons-outlined");
                if (x[0].style.display === "block") {
                    x[0].style.display = "none";
                    x[1].style.display = "none";
                    x[2].style.display = "none";
                    x[3].style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    x[0].style.display = "block";
                    x[1].style.display = "block";
                    x[2].style.display = "block";
                    x[3].style.display = "block";
                }
            }
```